# PostgreSQL - How to get the previous(lag) calculated value

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I would like to get the previous(lag) calculated value?

```
   id  | value
-------|-------
    1  |   1
    2  |   3
    3  |   5
    4  |   7
    5  |   9
```

What I am trying  to achieve is this:

```
   id  | value | new value
-------|-------|-----------
   1   |   1   |   10      <-- 1 * lag(new_value)
   2   |   3   |   30      <-- 3 * lag(new_value)
   3   |   5   |  150      <-- 5 * lag(new_value)
   4   |   7   | 1050      <-- 7 * lag(new_value)
   5   |   9   | 9450      <-- 9 * lag(new_value)
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT value,
       COALESCE(lag(new_value) OVER () * value, 10) AS new_value
FROM table
```

Error:

> ERROR:  column "new_value" does not exist

Comment: Looks like is a recursive calculation, isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes mate. What should I be using here? Recursive CTE or Lateral join?

Comment: Recursive CTE. should be easy. Let me know if need more help https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: How your values are `{1,2,3,4,5}` but then become  `{1,3,5,7,9}` ?

Comment: That's a typo, my bad. I wanted to show that the initial set is random.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need `coalesce()` with lag. You can pass a default value directly to the `lag()` function: `lag(some_col, 1, 0)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nice. That will help to clean-up the code. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Juan's answer but I thought I'd post it anyway. It at least avoids the need for the ID column and doesn't have the empty row at the end:

```
with recursive all_data as (
  select value, value * 10 as new_value
  from data
  where value = 1

  union all

  select c.value, 
         c.value * p.new_value
  from data c
    join all_data p on p.value < c.value
  where c.value = (select min(d.value) 
                   from data d 
                   where d.value > p.value)
)
select *
from all_data
order by value;
```

The idea is to join exactly one row in the recursive part to exactly one "parent" row. While the "exactly one parent" can be done with a derived table and a lateral join (which surprisingly *does* allow the `limit`). The "exactly one row" from the "child" in the recursive part can unfortunately only be done using the sub-select with a `min()`.

The `where c.value= (...)` wouldn't be necessary if it was possible to use an `order by` and `limit` in the recursive part as well, but unfortunately that is not supported in the current Postgres version.

Online example: http://rextester.com/WFBVM53545

Comment: Nice. I'll give your example a go. I am still trying to get Juan's to work. What i did get to work was limit and offset. Just wrap each statement in brackets. `(SELECT ..... LIMIT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT .... OFFSET 1)`.

Comment: I would change the base case with `MIN(value)` as OP explain the data is random.

Comment: Yes, that `order by - limit` restriction make my life misserable :(

Comment: Changing  the lateral join to `join all_data p on p.value < c.value` is 50% faster...

Comment: @Willem: you are right that isn't actually needed with the `select min()`

Answer (score 1):

My bad, this isnt that easy as I thought. Got a very close result but still need some tunning.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MTWGZH35463)**

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n, v) AS (
    SELECT MIN(value), 10 
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL
    SELECT (SELECT min(value) from Table1 WHERE value > n), 
           (SELECT min(value) from Table1 WHERE value > n) * v
    FROM t
    JOIN Table1 on t.n = Table1.value    
)    
SELECT n, v 
FROM t;
```

**[image: OUTPUT]**

Comment: At least you got results. +1

Comment: would be easier if you add a id on your table ;)

Comment: I have id's. So you can change it to work of id's. I'll update the question

Comment: You shouldnt accept, maybe someone else found the correct answer. Unless you found it in that case, please post it.